# SQL query to return all data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

For example, I have 2 tables, `tableA` and `tableB`.

```
tableA
id    name    age
1     nameA   10
2     nameB   11

tableB
id    name    age    address
3     nameC   10      test
4     nameD   11      test
```

When I use `SELECT * FROM tableA FULL OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id`, I get

```
id    name    age   id    name    age    address
1     nameA   10
2     nameB   11
                    3     nameC   10      test
                    4     nameD   11      test
```

Is there a way to merge the data properly?

Something like this:

```
id    name    age    address
1     nameA   10
2     nameB   11
3     nameC   10      test
4     nameD   11      test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables are not related by the column `id` on which you tried to join them so you need `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *, null address FROM tableA 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM tableB
```

Since `tableA` has only 3 columns, a 4th dummy `null`column was added to it to match the number of columns of `tableB`.